# CGFloat Value Assignment Error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a strange issue working on a new iOS (v7 SDK) app while working with CGFloat. A test photograph with dimensions 2448w X 3264h (saved in photographSize) is creating errors when I try to get its width and save it to a CGFloat. Here is how the code looks:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Photograph;
...
UIImage *photographImage = Photograph.image;
CGSize photographSize = [photographImage size];
...
CGFloat photoScale = photographSize.width;
```

photoScale is incorrectly being assigned the value 7.6500001 instead of 2448. What gives? Is this a sign of over/underflow happening? I have verified the values in photographSize to be 2448w X 3264h in the debugger. Also, Photograph is a UIImageView.

Thanks, I will monitor this thread throughout the day.

Comment: There can be no over/underflow in that assignment, so `photographSize` must already contain the "wrong" value. Did you check it in the debugger?

Comment: show code related to `photographSize`

Comment: Added a bit more code. Digging for relevant snippets.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense given `CGSize` elements are `CGFloat` there cannot be an under/overflow.  Have you checked both source and destination after the assignment?  My feeling is that the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: May issue, when assigning image to photographImage that is UIImage *photographImage = Photograph.image; . I try in myself but using another image and its working me fine. Double check your code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a mistake? Should be

```
CGSize photographScaledSize = Photograph.bounds.size;
CGFloat photoScale = photographScaledSize.width;
                               ^^^^^^
```

Comment: I updated the code and clarified the question, it was my mistake to post the first line. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @LukePrince So? Doesn't help? Then post more code, please.

Answer (score 1):

Update source code like below

```
CGFloat photoScale = photographSize.width;
```

to

```
CGFloat photoScale = photographScaledSize.width;
```

Comment: I already pointed on that. See answers posted, otherwise there is a *possibility* that you post duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I used you code with my image and its working me fine. May be there is issue at assign image to `UIImage *photographImage`

```
    UIImage *photographImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7_normal.png"];
    CGSize photographSize = [photographImage size];
    CGFloat photoScale = photographSize.width;
```